# audit-argument-checks with bad packages

Tags: meteor

I want to use `audit-argument-checks` package in meteor to make sure that I am checking all arugments correctly.

But some other packages that I am importing such as [`gadicohen:headers`](https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/headers) are not compliant.

I is there a way to enable audit check just for my code and not for the packages I am using that may not be as compliant.

Comment: Create your own methods which uses `check()`, and once validated, call the methods provided by the package, server-side.

Comment: headers provides a server side method that it's client side js calls, ```'headersToken'``` and you cannot override a Metor.method. This code is also implemented inline so no monkey patching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into this frequently - the package ecosystem lets you get things done easily, but not always well. Usually, I'll clone the package into my own packages folder in the meteor project folder, make changes, then submit a pull request to the original author so the change makes its way to other people. With the audit-argument-checks package in your project, usually this involves adding the check package to the packages.js file using api.use('check'), then fixing the methods to check parameters.